# Setting up a rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, partial-views

I have two models, users and pins.

In my Pins model, I have an index view where I render the partial of ALL pins:

index.html.erb: `<%= render @pins %>`

_pins.html.erb : `pin.content`

My pins controller is basically:

```
def index
    @pins = Pin.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
    end
  end
```

Above, the rendering works fine.

However, for my User model, I have a show view where I want to render a partial to give me a list of just the *current user's* pins:

show.html.erb: `<%= render @user.mypin %>`

_mypin.html.erb : `user.pin.content` and `user.pin.privacy`

My user controller is basically:

```
def show 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @pins = Pin.all
end
```

I keep getting the following error:
NoMethodError in Users#show
Showing .../app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #11 raised:
undefined method `mypin' for User:0x00000103d2c130

I need the two partials to remain separate (because I begin to render different stuff in each page i.e. privacy etc)...Is there a way to do something like <%= render :partial => "mypin", @user.pins %> ?

Comment: What do your User and Pin models look like?

Comment: Did you even read the error message?

Comment: My user and pin models have the correct associations for has_many and belongs_to, as I indicated below.

Answer (score 3):

`User#mypin` seems to not be defined in your `User` model.

You should define a `has_many` relation between your `User` model and your `Pin` model like so:

```
class User
  has_many :pins
end

class Pin
  belongs_to :user
end

@user = User.find(params[:id])
@pins = @user.pins
#=> will returns all user's pins
```

Then you can use it in your view:

```
<%= render @pins %>
```

Comment: But I do have the has_many and belongs_to defined in my User and Pin models (exactly as you have it).  Also, I need the partials to remain separate because I am rendering different values for the all pins page vs. the user pins page...

Comment: I did update my user controller to say @pins = @user.pins as you suggested. Now I am getting the error: undefined method `mypin'

Comment: Is there a way to do something like <%= render :partial => "mypin", @user.pins  %> ?

Comment: Like so: `<%= render partial: 'mypin', collection: @user.pins %>`